# GAM Predictions in R have same curve shape

Tags: r, mgcv

I have a dataframe:

```
   Albedo Year_Since_Burn Summer_SRAD Winter_SRAD
1  397.00               1    17801.70     6589.56
2  289.60               2    18027.20     6633.96
3  615.29               3    17397.10     6952.69
4  258.12               4    17793.63     6627.62
5  139.32               5    17853.00     6675.00
6  463.81               6    17853.00     6675.00
7  532.47               7    17853.00     6675.00
8  300.09               8    17648.00     6890.00
9  118.00               9    17786.13     6724.67
10 238.18              10    18050.13     6916.46
11 439.11              11    18057.20     6893.08
12 366.00              12    17823.00     6618.12
13 441.25              13    17809.50     6673.79
14 450.31              14    17654.40     6849.19
15 275.43              15    17592.80     7202.88
16 147.11              16    17830.20     6672.88
17 285.68              17    18065.13     6897.58
18 309.61              18    17665.80     7036.62
19 264.95              19    18053.47     6867.17
20 125.18              20    17834.40     6661.19
21 289.50              21    17824.00     6684.50
22 293.61              22    17826.90     6681.83
23 368.95              23    17634.55     6914.06
24 563.11              24    17434.23     7043.04
25 434.41              25    17527.60     7070.38
26 199.78              26    17955.40     6704.00
27 153.37              27    17872.70     6637.00
28 287.29              28    17843.20     6659.67
29 173.52              29    17822.93     6616.75
30 239.28              30    17884.00     6580.56
31 292.91              31    17884.00     6580.56
32 323.00              32    18078.70     6758.50
33 282.00              33    18078.70     6758.50
34 237.50              34    17779.10     7303.38
35 225.00              35    17822.80     6617.42
36 237.55              36    17822.80     6617.42
37 247.11              37    17918.50     6695.71
38 336.48              38    17918.50     6695.71
39 290.00              39    17918.50     6695.71
40 248.42              40    17822.80     6617.42
41 304.74              41    17918.50     6695.71
42 311.52              42    17918.50     6695.71
43 281.39              43    17918.50     6695.71
44 234.68              44    17918.50     6695.71
45 297.58              45    17918.50     6695.71
46 265.52              46    17918.50     6695.71
47 186.29              47    17918.50     6695.71
48 291.16              48    17918.50     6695.71
49 185.17              49    17918.50     6695.71
50 288.94              50    17918.50     6695.71
51 269.64              51    17918.50     6695.71
52 255.00              52    17918.50     6695.71
```

I am fitting a GAM model in R like so:

```
gam.m1 <- gam(Albedo ~ s(Year_Since_Burn) + s(Summer_SRAD) + s(Winter_SRAD), data=df)
```

which seems to work fine, and returns result as I would expect.

I have now created some data to predict on.  Essentially I randomly selected 2 rows in the original df, duplicated them 52 times each, and then removed the `Year_Since_Burn` and `Albedo` columns, and created some new `Year_Since_Burn` data.  So I only manipulated one independent variable. I did this like so:

```
df <- df[sample(nrow(df), 2),]

df <- df %>% select (-c(Albedo, Year_Since_Burn))

#add an id columns
df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))

#loop through each row
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  #select each row
  grp <- (df[i, ])

  #repeat each row 52 times
  grp <- grp[rep(seq_len(nrow(grp)), each=52),]

  #add a column for year since burn
  grp$Year_Since_Burn <- seq.int(nrow(grp))

  #select rows to keep
  grp <- grp %>% select (c(ID, Year_Since_Burn,Summer_SRAD, Winter_SRAD, Winter_Tavg, Summer_Tavg, PFI, Bulk_Density, 
                          SOC_Content, SOC_Stock, L3_Ecoregion))

  #append
  combined[[i]] <- grp
}

#concat
final = do.call(rbind, combined)
```

Now for each unique `ID` in `final` I predicted the dependent variable like so:

```
y_hat <-  predict(gam.m1, final)
```

and then I plotted to look at how the predictions varied with `Year_Since_Burn`:

```
final2 <- data.frame(as.array(final$ID), as.array(final$Year_Since_Burn), y_hat2)
names(final2) <- c("ID", 'Year_Since_Burn', "Predicted")

#plot
plots1 <- lapply(split(final2, final2$ID), 
                 function(x) 
                   ggplot(x, aes(x=Year_Since_Burn, y=Predicted)) +
                   geom_line())
```

For the output graphs the curves are identical in shape for every prediction, it is just the magnitudes that are shifting.  I am not sure if this is what GAMs is supposed to do or if this is an error on my part.  This is what the predictions for two different Id's look like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the reproducible, runnable code to create `df`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. The shape of the predictions should not change when you predict the same old model on new data. The shape of the predicted values vs the year since burn (or any other variables) **is** the fitted model. The residuals will change. But the parameters of the model determine the shape of that curve you plot, and they are determined during the fitting step, not the prediction step.

Comment: The surprising thing to me is that the magnitude shifted at all, but as your question isn't reproducible I can't do much to investigate further.

Comment: I'm working on making it reproducible right now, thank you for  your input

Comment: Ok hopefully the edit helps.  I guess what I am getting hung up on is when I use a Random Forest Model and I train it and then predict with it in the same manner as here the output is different for every curve, so I though it would be with GAM too.

Comment: To me, the GAM works as I would expect and I'm surprised by what you say about a random forest. Now that your example is reproducible, the plots are identical as I would expect. You seem confused about the differences between fitting (training) and prediction, but I'm not clear how to answer this question. Here you get the same predictions for the same inputs. (Not identical inputs, but the same ranges).  If you get different predictions on the same inputs on your random forest, that seems like a problem.

Comment: But the curves aren't exactly identical are they?  On the second graph the curve is shifted up on the y-axis very slightly. If the input variables are different (the inputs here are different as well) the random forest will predict a different outcome because different routes in the tree are taken, and therefore the predicted output should be different too.  At least this is how I understand it.  I would start a discussion but I don't know how to without the prompt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154462/discussion-between-stefano-potter-and-gregor).